# Problems interacting between Business logic, dbml and other compiled classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, signalr

Hi so I am currently build my first ASP.Net app whilst learning C# at the same time so please excuse any seemingly stupid statements.

What I have so far is an SQL db with Linq to SQL dbml and some business logic which is accessible directly from my default.aspx ObjectDataSource. This renders fine with gets and async posts.

I am trying to move to SSE with signalR to push updates to all clients connected. The problem is no compiled classes can access the methods in the context classes in the App_Code folder.

I assume I could still query the SQL db directly but I wish to use the existing Linq. How can I access the content file methods from my compile methods.

Here is my BL:

```
public partial class WallBAL
{
    public List<Statuses> getStatuses()
    {
        var context = new WallDataContext();
        var query = from x in context.Statuses
                select x;
        this.StatusList = query.ToList<Statuses>();
        return query.ToList<Statuses>();

    }

    public void insertStatus()
    {

    }



    public List<Statuses> StatusList { get; set; }
}
```

Solving this access issue would mean it would be very easy to define the insert method too.

Answer (score 0):

So I kind of solved this. When I create the dbml in the project root rather than App_Code.data, and add the BL to the classes folder I can access the methods